# Como puedo ejecutar una función php al pulsar un enlace

Tags: php, html

Un saludo, Quisiera que me ayudaran ya que deseo que al pulsar en un link `<a href="#">`, se desencadene una función php que esta en otro fichero,

Comment: Podrias proporcionar mas detalle de que es lo que quieres hacer para poder ayudarte de una mejor manera

Comment: Si pones el código de lo que has intentado hacer sería de ayuda. Sin el codigo te diria de mezclar ajax y php

Comment: Las respuestas anteriones son validas, pero tambien podrias colocar en tu href el php, y que cuando este termine de ejecutarse, habra la supuesta pagina del href con un header(); Saludos

Comment: Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora `<li><a href="ControladorUsuario.php?accion=borrar">Cerrar sesión</a></li>`             y en la pagina php el codigo es lo siguiente `function destruirSeccion(){
   SESSION_START();
   SESSION_UNSET();
   SESSION_DESTROY();   
   header('Location: InicioSesion.php');
  }

  if($accion="borrar"){
   destruirSeccion();
  }
`, pero lo que deseo es que la funcion se ejecute directamente si el paso de variable

Comment: PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y JavaScript en el local , por consiguiente te aconsejo que lo hagas con JavaScript o JQuery si lo ves factible. En otro caso haz que ese link sea un input con submit y trátalo como un formulario.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) y hacer lo siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="irFuncion();">Ejecutar función PHP</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  function irFuncion(){
    $.ajax({
    // aqui va la ubicación de la página PHP
      url: 'urlPaginaPHP',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { condicion: "ejecutarFuncion"},
      success:function(resultado){
       // imprime "resultado Funcion"
       alert(resultado);
      }
  }
</script>
```

**PaginaPHP**

```
<?php 
  // verificas que si llegue el parámetro que le estas enviando
 if(isset($_REQUEST["condicion"])){
  // si llega la condicion, y es igual a la condicion que necesitas para entrar ejecuta la función y devuelve el resultado
  if($_REQUEST["condicion"] == "ejecutarFuncion" ){
     echo funcionPHP();
     // salimos de la pagina php y devolvemos la respuesta
     exit();
  }else{
     echo "otra funcion o respuesta";
     // salimos de la pagina php y devolvemos la respuesta
     exit();
  }
 }

 function funcionPHP(){
    return "resultado Funcion";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Esta bien tu consejo pero deseo llamar la funcion directamente sin necesidad del echo, tiene alguna idea ?, esto lo pregunto por que el fichero donde se aloja la funcion se esta utilizando por mas ficheros

Comment: Agregue una condicion, asi podrás controlar mejor lo que retornas de tu pagina [tag:php]

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tienes la siguiente estructura en tu proyecto:

```
  MyWebsite/
  |--css/
  |--fonts/
  |--js/
  |--index.php
  |--archivo_a_ejecutar.php
```

Puedes colocar la ruta a tu archivo directamente en el atributo href

```
<a href="http://localhost/MyWebsite/archivo_a_ejecutar.php">Ejecutar función PHP</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando **ajax** mi estimado

```
<a href="#" onclick="go();">obtener funcion</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function go(){
   $.post("includes/mifuncion.php",
        {
                //parametros
                comand: "selectQuery",

            },
            function(data,status){                  

            });
 }
```

**mifuncion.php**

```
$comando = $_POST['comand'];
switch ($comando) {
    case "selectQuery":
        echo select();
        break;
    case "updateQuery":
        echo update();
        break;
    case "deleteQuery":
        echo delete();
        break;
}
function select(){
}
fuction update(){
}
function delete(){
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Miguel Osorio, solo una pregunta en esta linea ` $.post("includes/mifuncion.php"` el include me imagino que es la carpeta donde esta alojada el fichero php

Comment: asi es es la carpeta donde esta el fichero